# how to show jasper report in the browser?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

i have this:

```
String generado="/Users/MyUser/Documents/libros/HelloJasper.pdf";
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, generado);
```

this keeps the pdf in the specified path, but I want to display it in the browser.I would like to have the option to keep it in the computer after seeing it in the browser . Thank you.

Comment: after export open it from java. `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Open HTML file using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517434/how-to-open-html-file-using-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open External Application From JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898704/open-external-application-from-javafx)

Comment: I want, after seeing prompted save on your computer.

Comment: @JUANCAMILOARBOLEDAGUTIÉRREZ so do it after prompt.what's the problem?

Comment: I would like to have the option to keep it in the computer after seeing it in the browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Pdf in browser using java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint =JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,beanColDataSource);
JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Are you going to show report with help of JasperViewer? Are you sure?